# EJB 3.0 circular dependencies

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, circular-dependency

We have hundreds of EJBs. Recently created a new patch which doesn't deploy correctly in our JAS: JBoss 4.2 and gives errors like the following at deployment time:

--- MBeans waiting for other MBeans ---
ObjectName: jboss.j2ee:ear=Ear.ear,jar=Business.jar,name=Locator,service=EJB3
  State: NOTYETINSTALLED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.j2ee:ear=Ear.ear,jar=Business.jar,name=MaintenanceWorkLoadInterceptor,service=EJB3
    jboss.j2ee:ear=Ear.ear,jar=Business.jar,name=CustomerDao,service=EJB3
    jboss.j2ee:ear=Ear.ear,jar=Business.jar,name=DrilldownEquipmentActivityAction,service=EJB3
    jboss.j2ee:ear=Ear.ear,jar=Business.jar,name=GeoLocDao,service=EJB3
    jboss.j2ee:ear=Ear.ear,jar=Business.jar,name=PackageTaskForInfoTabDao,service=EJB3
    jboss.j2ee:ear=Ear.ear,jar=System.jar,name=AutomatedTestLogDao,service=EJB3
    jboss.j2ee:ear=Ear.ear,jar=Business.jar,name=ModstateHistoryDao,service=EJB3
    jboss.j2ee:ear=Ear.ear,jar=System.jar,name=TaskSchedulerCommandHandler,service=EJB3
    jboss.j2ee:ear=Ear.ear,jar=Business.jar,name=CommonSupportValidationController,service=EJB3
    jboss.j2ee:ear=Ear.ear,jar=Business.jar,name=AssetEventValidationController,service=EJB3

...hundreds more listed. In any case I believe this is due to a circular dependency. The problem is since we have literally hundreds of EJBs, manually searching through them to try to find where the circular dependency is - is extremely time consuming.

I was thinking about writing a tool to check / find circular dependencies, but not wanting to re-invent the wheel I tried to search google for such a tool but had no luck. I can't believe that there isn't already a tool out there.

What is the best way to find these problems and fix them when you have as many EJBs as we do without manually going through each one?

Comment: Go to the versioning system, check differences between patch and last stable release and start from it...

Comment: Move to a real EE 5 app server, EJB 3.0 is fine with circular deps.

Comment: Following up months later... We ended up writing our own using the APT (Annotation Processing Tool): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/apt/index.html

I want to upgrade to a new JBoss version, but that's beyond my control.